# What is the default behavior of a std::map if, rather than the value, the KEY is a std::list or std::vector?

Tags: c++, dictionary

For example, these cases:

```cpp
using stringlist = std::list<string>;
    
std::map<stringlist, int> orderedMap;
std::unordered_map<stringlist, int> unorderedMap;
```

How will comparing keys in `orderedMap` work? Would it compare all items ('sub-keys') in the key one by one in lexical order?

How will computing hash in `unorderedMap` work?

Comment: To compare keys, you will need to define a comparator function. The behaviour might even be undefined. Ask yourself this... what will be the result of comparison of 2 vectors? Something like : `std::vector<int> vec1; std::vector<int> vec2; return vec1 > vec2;`. Also, did you try doing it on your own?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An ordered `map`, by default, uses `std::less` to compare keys, which by default just does `lhs < rhs`.

The behavior of `vector`'s `operator <` is described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

And that of `list` is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/operator_cmp

Yes, they just do a lexicographical comparison, i.e. they compare their elements one by one.

You can override the behavior by supplying a custom comparison as the third template parameter to `map`.

---

The default behavior of `unordered_map` is to use `std::hash`. `std::hash` does not have specializations for `vector` and `list`, so they are not usable as keys. The code should not compile. Try it here: https://godbolt.org/z/kgKmKS

You need to override the behavior by supplying a custom hasher as the third template argument to `unordered_map`. You can use Boost.Hash, which supports the standard containers: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html

Comment: Can you please explain why [this](https://pastebin.com/ij9WPR2g) does not work?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 You can't sort a `std::map` - it is always ordered by the ordering of its keys.

Comment: `std::hash does not have specializations for vector and list, so they are not usable as keys.` Unless you provide those specialisations, that is.

Comment: @eerorika Pretty sure you're not allowed to, unless it's specifically for a `std::vector<YourOwnType>`

Comment: @SebastianRedl Oh yea, good point. It could simply be `struct YourOwnType { stringlist s; };` though.